# url rewrite and A/B Testing in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I have my site that uses web.config to set url rewriting.
I cannot change the match url but I want to change (in example for odd days and for even days) the url for the action.
In particular:

```
<rule name="ricerca21pSEONew" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([_A-Z0-9a-z-=%]+)/p([0-9]+)[\/]?$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="new-sitesearch.aspx?idprestaz={R:2}&amp;prov=domicilio&amp;base={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```

should change url to new-sitesearch-speed.aspx for even days
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think conditions can be placed in the web.config file...

What I would do is create 2 web.config files:

- one with rule "new-sitesearch.aspx"
- one with rule "new-sitesearch-speed.aspx

Then create a batch that goes to copy / replace the web.config via Windows scheduled tasks.

Otherwise you should program a single aspx page with if statements based on the date